# Errors when using the SCP client from SharpSSH

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, scp

I am using SharpSSH (http://sharpssh2.codeplex.com/) to send files from a windows box(using C#) to a linux box. I use the Sftp class to create directories(mkdir command) and Sftp.put command to transfer files over to the Linux machine.

When the number of concurrent users is large about 30 or more then the connections being to drop and the mkdir and SFTP.put commands being to fail.

Is this something to do with reconfiguring the sshd_config params (on the linux box) to allow more connections, or do I have to make some adjustments on the Windows Client which is making the scp/sftp calls to transfer files?

Or am I using a unreliable SSH client (SharpSSH) and should look out for alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a MaxSessions attribute in sshd_config - have you checked the value of that?